# How can I move this rounded rectangle green outline further down

Tags: swiftui

[image]
[image]
I would like the first image(green outline) to match the second image(blue outline). I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I move the rounded rectangle(green outline) further down to match how the second image would look like. I attached my code so far below. Please let me know if I need any more information.

```
var color1 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
var color2 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137503, green: 0.8235294223, blue: 0.4196078479, alpha: 1)
    var width: CGFloat = 300
    var height: CGFloat = 100
    var percent: CGFloat = 7
    @Binding var show: Bool
```

```
var body: some View {
    let multiplier = width / 44
    let progress = 1 - percent / 100

    return ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
            .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.1), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: multiplier))
            .frame(width: width, height: height)

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)

            .trim(from: show ? 0.90 : 1, to: 1)
            .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(color1), Color(color2)]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing),
                    style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2 * multiplier, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: .infinity, dash: [20,0], dashPhase: 0))
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result by changing the `trim` start and end position
 to the following.

`.trim(from: show ? 0.90 : 0.93, to: 0.93)`

**Result:**
[image]